# Node JS spawn result: python3: can't open file './test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, typescript, child-process

So I'm trying to run a simple python file called test.py through the Node JS child process, however it keeps saying that `python3: can't open file './test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I tried everything to fix this error. For example, the python script ran successfully from the same directory the typescript file is present, I even tried the full path, the relative path for the python file and it still didn't work. I kindly request someone too look into this, thank you!

test.py

```py
    import sys
    print("hello world")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

```js
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = await spawn("python3", ['./test.py']);
let dataMain = "";
child.stdout.on("data", (data: Buffer) => {
    // Do something with the data returned from python script
    console.log(data); // buffer data
    dataMain += data.toString();
});

child.stdout.on("end", () => {
     console.log("end");
     console.log(dataMain);
});
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr); // prints out the error
```

Comment: Do check whether the file test.py is in same directory, or try to provide the complete directory to `spawn` method

Comment: Yep they are in the same directory.

Comment: your error says it is not. So give the absolute directory (`/home/user/Desktop/.../test.py, like that)

Comment: It worked when I did {process.cwd()}, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with `${process.cwd()}/test.py`

Comment: hey can you tell how to add that? like this?  var child= spawn('python', [ `${process.cwd()}/test.py`, arg1,arg2 ]); or some other way?